# get only the item you click on

Tags: menus

I want to save the current items class id, when i click on a menu item.
The problem is, that when i click on a submenu item, it will run the jQuery multiple times,
because the items classes have the same name. So the javascript alerts more than one time.
It seems as when a parent li has the same class name as the child, it will run the jQuery code for both of them.
How can i avoid the jQuery to run for the parent li ?

html:

```
<li id="menu-item-2139" class="menu-item">Item 1
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-2151" class="menu-item">Item 2</li>
        <li id="menu-item-2564" class="menu-item">Item 3
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-2567" class="menu-item">Item 4</li>
                <li id="menu-item-2570" class="menu-item">Item 5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.menu-item').click(function(){
    var class_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    alert(class_id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called "event bubbling" or "event propagation" and the solution is to get the event object and use the JS `stopPropagation` method.  Try this:

```
jQuery('.menu-item').click(function(event){
    var class_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(class_id);
});
```